# Ordenar elementos em tela com CSS

Tags: css, angularjs

Estou replicando alguns botoes com o "ng-repeat" com angular, porém estou com dificuldades em ordenar esses botões na forma que desejo.
Eu quero que seja mostrado 4 botoes no lado inferior esquerdo e 4 botoes no lado inferior direito.
Não posso utilizar o slice pois atrapalharia em outro momento.

Código html:

```css
.btf {
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        height: 79px;
        background-color: #2E5491;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="page-header" id="principal">
        <div class="divpai">
            <span class="divbutton" ng-repeat="menuItem in teste  = data.alexa.item | filter:  menuSel ">
                <button id="btf1" ng-repeat="menu in menuItem.children.child" ng-click="selecionaMenu(menu['@attributes'].id)" class="btf">{{menu['@attributes'].id | label : mapaLabels}}</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que utilizar o sistema de grid do [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) resolveria o seu problema.

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Primeira linha com 4 botões -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- Botão -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <!-- Segunda linha com 4 botões -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- Botão -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Adapte esse código a sua necessidade e assim deve resolver o seu problemas.

Comment: entendo, e como eu chamaria ele no meu código ? pode exemplificar ? @flpn